# reverse geocoding multiple nodes

Tags: openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

My problem: need multiple nodes reverse geocoding. I use nominatim API

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=53.9135678&lon=27.5549758&zoom=18&addressdetails=1&accept-language=ru

I have many mane nodes (~800 000) and I want to reverse geocode all of them in order to have database like this

node | city | district | street | lat | lon

"lat" and "lon" I have already, but most of my nodes do not have streets, city, district, and I want to have them.

One solution I came up is the following. I can make about 1000 requests and then my ip gets blocked, and in an hour I can make 1000 requests again. Also I use proxies, thus making requests from different IP addresses. All this concurrently, so in total I can update 30 000 - 40 000 nodes per day. As you can see, to update my nodes, I will need many days.

There are drawbacks of this solution: speed, time, and overloading nominatim servers.

So what's are the better ideas? Also is it possible to download nodes for specific polygon (region with max lat, lon, min lat, lon) already reversed geocoded. In this case I will not need make multiple geocoding requests.

If you have ideas how I can achieve this using other APIs, google, Yandex, whatever, let me know please.

Best regards

Comment: Don't use proxies to circumvent Nominatim's usage limit. This server runs on donated servers and has a very limited capacity. Abusing it will be very unfair towards other users!

Comment: Of course! Now I don't go this way. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: Cross posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169878/multiple-nodes-reverse-geocoding-using-nominatim-api

Comment: Not Cross posted any more. I removed from
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169878/multiple-nodes-reverse-geocoding-using-nominatim-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't comply with the [usage policy of OSM's public Nominatim server](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy) then there are multiple options:

- Use one of the free [alternative/third-party providers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy#Alternatives_.2F_Third-party_providers) such as [MapQuest Open](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim) or [OpenCage Geocoder](http://geocoder.opencagedata.com/) (but check their terms of use first!)
- Use a geocoder from the list of [commercial OSM services](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Commercial_OSM_Software_and_Services)
- [Install your own Nominatim instance](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation)

Comment: Does MapQuest distinguish its MapQuest Open API from its other geocoding APIs?  I could not find anywhere they do so, and in general they only permit their geocoding data (lat/lng) to be used on a MapQuest map, which is rather limiting.